# PNG image loses anti aliasing after css width transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a logo image that has its width reduced when the user scrolls down, and regains it as they scroll up. Problem is that it loses it anti-aliasing after transitioning like so:

before
[image]

after
[image]

(pardon the lines below it, that's just the rest of the navbar)

This seems to only happen in Chrome.

Logo's css

```
.logo {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

css of small logo class that gets added by Javascript on scroll down and removed on up

```
.header-top-mini .logo {
    width: 200px;
}
```

I've tried some of the other threads on here that have a similar problem and nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try using transform: scale(Xdeg); or change image file type to svg? well, not sure if this will do the trick

Comment: turning it into svg did it. thanks

Comment: make an actual response and I'll pick yours as the right ansewr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try using transform: scale(Xdeg); or change image file type to svg? well, not sure if this will do the trick

EDIT*

just some additional info about svg scaling
https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score 0):

Try [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).  The "auto" property is supported in Chrome.

```
img {
  image-rendering: auto;
}
```

Comment: I would change the question into a statement if I were you. For example, "Try image-rendering". Some close-happy people might flag your answer as not an answer.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. It's still doing it. Also I second what t-rav said

Comment: To @ShayanJavadi, sorry that didn't work.  I'll keep searching around and see if I can find anything for ya.